# Is asking a question obviously answered on another website considered a bad behavior?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

It does help the Stack Overflow website to grow, in my opinion, but I can see lots of people simply posting links and downvoting these type of questions.

**Should these kinds of questions be avoided at all and just remain present on other websites exclusively?**

Comment: "simply posting links" Do you mean to the questions, or as answers?

Comment: @Josh Caswell as answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's bad behavior.

As per the help center, people are expected to do their research before asking questions.  Asking a question where the answer is readily accessible, whether that answer is on SO or not, is not doing your research.

SO as a site is designed to be a repository of *quality* content.  The site goes out of its way to remove content that's not valuable, and to help the content that *is* valuable shine.  "Growing" the site by filling it with low quality content that's not actually adding value isn't helping the site.  This is evidenced by all of SO's competitors that go to such lengths to ensure that just about any type of question is allowed, not turning away much of anything, with the end result that the flood of trash makes users not want to go there.

Comment: I would add that if the question is self-answered (and the answer isn't plagiarized from the other site), then it's fine.

Comment: @NicolBolas How so?  How is that any more valuable than if it's not?  Note that questions are judged on their own merit, and the standards are no different for a self answered question than it is for any other question.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I feel like Servy made a great point by specifying the fact that this sites grows with **quality** content and rewriting a self answered question would fall in the lower quality side of things.

Comment: @Servy: "*How is that any more valuable than if it's not?*" Because it's preserved on this site, rather than on some other site. There are many questions that get asked every day that could technically be answered by linking you to some part of some other site. That doesn't make them bad questions.

Comment: @NicolBolas So why is it better for it to be on this site than on some other site?  Asking a question for which the answer is readily accessible elsewhere *is* asking a bad question.  It's asking a poorly researched question, and a question should be well researched for it to be a good question.